# SQL Server 2014 query with multiple conditions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I've got an SQL query with multiple conditions, for the given Source(listed below) I need to get the result set as Final (listed below)  with the following condition:

- Condition 01: For the active site, contact with ‘RO’ as contact role should be taken
- Condition 02: For the inactive site, contact with ‘Owner’ as contact role should be taken
- Condition 03: If the active site doesn't have contact with ‘RO’ as contact role, then contact with 'Owner' as contact role should be taken
- Condition 04: If the inactive site doesn't have contact with ‘Owner’ as contact role, then contact with 'RO' as contact role should be taken
- Condition 05: If the active site/inactive doesn't have contact with ‘RO’  or ‘Owner’ as contact role, then contact with ‘Operator’ as contact role should be taken
- Condition 06: Only for active site avoid 'XYZ' contact with 'RO' as contact role and pick another contact with 'RO'as contact role, if the site doesn't have 'RO' then pick 'Owner' or 'operator' as contact role
- Condition 07: If the site (active/inactive) doesn't have any contacts, then those sites should have 'NULL' values in the contact field.

Can we include all the above conditions in one single query (without subqueries if possible) as original data set records are more than 20K?

```
Source 
======

Site_Status Site_id  Site_Contact  Contact Role 
Active      123      Lilly         Owner
Active      123      Elan          RO
Inactive    345      Rose          Owner
Inactive    345      Jack          RO
Active      678      Robert        Owner 
Inactive    912      Linda         RO
Active      234      Nike          Operator 
Inactive    456      Frank         Operator
Active      808      XYZ           RO
Active      808      Kelly         Owner
Active      999      XYZ           RO
Active      999      Debbi         Operator 
Active      122                
Inactive    188              


Final
======
Site_Status Site_id Site_Contact    ContactRole
Active      123     Elan            RO
Inactive    345     Rose            Owner
Active      678     Robert          Owner
Inactive    912     Linda           RO
Active      234     Nick            Operator
Inactive    456     Frank           Operator
Active      808     Kelly           Owner
Active      999     Debbi           Operator 
Active      122     NULL            NULL
Inactive    188     NULL            NULL
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes... using the `AND` operator. What does your current query look like?

Comment: Can you post your data in a consumable format instead of an image? Why? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557 Here is a great place to get an idea of a better way to post data. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Don't take @SeanLange advice lightly. From now on, don't use pictures... use a DDL with sample data as i have provided in my answer.

Comment: I'm new to this site and I'm learning how to post it properly. Thank you the for the useful link. I will keep in mind next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this... using a window function and conditional sorting.

```
declare @YourTable table (Site_Status varchar(64), Site_id int, Site_Contact varchar(64), ContactRole varchar(64))
insert into @YourTable
values
('Active',123,'Lilly','Owner'),
('Active',123,'Elan','RO'),
('Inactive',345,'Rose','Owner'),
('Inactive',345,'Jack','RO'),
('Active',678,'Robert','Owner'),
('Inactive',912,'Linda','RO'),
('Active',234,'Nick','Operator'),
('Inactive',456,'Frank','Operator')

select
    t.*
from @YourTable t
inner join
    (select 
        Site_id
        ,Site_Status
        ,ContactRole
        ,Active = row_number() over (partition by Site_id, Site_Status order by case 
                                                                                    when Site_Status = 'Active' and ContactRole = 'RO' then 1
                                                                                    when Site_Status = 'Active' and ContactRole = 'Owner' then 2
                                                                                    when Site_Status = 'Active' and ContactRole = 'Operator' then 3
                                                                                end)
        ,InActive = row_number() over (partition by Site_id, Site_Status order by case
                                                                                    when Site_Status = 'InActive' and ContactRole = 'Owner' then 1
                                                                                    when Site_Status = 'InActive' and ContactRole = 'RO' then 2
                                                                                    when Site_Status = 'InActive' and ContactRole = 'Operator' then 3
                                                                                end)
    from @YourTable) x on 
    x.Site_id = t.Site_id 
    and x.Site_Status =  t.Site_Status 
    and t.ContactRole = x.ContactRole 
    and Active = 1 
    and InActive = 1
```

Comment: Much appreciated. It helped a lot.

Comment: No worries at all @user119260

Comment: Using your logic greatly reduce the runtime of query compare to the subqueries. I really appreciate it again. But I got two more conditions(06 &07) request to include in the query. Can you please help me how to incorporate those conditions in your same logic.

Comment: @user119260 it's best to open a new question as it will garner more attention than this one, which is old for this site.

Comment: I'm able to include condition 06 in the query by adding where clause as where Site_contact <> 'XYZ'  for the 'x' table. I'm working on condition 07, if I can't do it then I will open that as new questions. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a table variable and populate it gradually, but it won't be a single query (it is a ggod candidate for a stored procedure). A single query with subqueries can be created using union (a rather big one):

```
select * from [Source]
where [Contact Role] = 'RO' and Site_Status = 'Active'
union
select * from [Source]
where [Contact Role] = 'Owner' and Site_Status = 'Inactive'
union
select * from [Source] s1
where [Contact Role] = 'Owner' and Site_Status = 'Active'
and not exists(
    select 1 from [Source] s2 where s1.Site_Id = s2.Site_id 
    and s2.Site_Status = 'Active' and s2.[Contact Role] = 'RO'
)
union
select * from [Source] s1
where [Contact Role] = 'RO' and Site_Status = 'Inactive'
and not exists(
    select 1 from [Source] s2 where s1.Site_Id = s2.Site_id 
    and s2.Site_Status = 'Inactive' and s2.[Contact Role] = 'Owner'
)
union
select * from [Source] s1
where [Contact Role] = 'Operator'
and not exists(
    select 1 from [Source] s2 where s1.Site_Id = s2.Site_id 
    and (s2.[Contact Role] = 'Owner' or s2.[Contact Role] = 'RO')
)
```